# Change service location on Mule

Tags: service, mule

my first try was to simple proxy a service from one location to another, and it work just fine, right now i need some help in how to change part of the service location, for example, the retrieved WSDL point 4 services to a machine, i need to change 1 of those services for another server, is that even possible? If so, how do i do it?

Mule Version CE 3.4.

my code atm is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ssl="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https"
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern"
xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.4/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.4/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/3.4/mule-pattern.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.4/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl/current/mule-ssl.xsd" version="EE-3.4.0">

<mule-ss:security-manager>
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
        name="memory-dao" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>

<spring:beans>
    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
                <ss:user name="asd" password="asd" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </ss:user-service>
        </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>

<https:connector name="httpsConnector">
<https:tls-key-store path="${mule.home}/conf/keystore.jks"
    keyPassword="1234567" storePassword="1234567" />
</https:connector>

<pattern:web-service-proxy name="Service"
      inboundAddress="https://LocalAdress.com:443/services/Service"
      outboundAddress="http://RemoteAddress.com/services/Service.svc"
      wsdlLocation="http://RemoteAddress.com/services/Service.svc?singleWSDL"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mule doesn't offer a mechanism to realize this type of WSDL customization. What you have to do is:

- download "http://RemoteAddress.com/services/Service.svc?singleWSDL",
- customize it by hand,
- embed the customized version in your project (say in "src/main/resources"),
- serve it with `wsdlFile="yourCustom.wsdl"`